# Как в массив чисел записать длины строк из массива строк?

Tags: java

Имеется массив строк и массив чисел.

Элементы массива строк вводятся с клавиатуры.

Моя задача: в каждую ячейку массива чисел записать длину строки из массива строк, индекс/номер ячейки которой совпадает с текущим индексом из массива чисел.

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String[] list = new String[10];

        int[] list2 = new int[10];

        for(int i = 0; i<list.length; i++){
            list[i] = reader.readLine();
        }

        // здесь нужно записать длинны строк в массив list2

        for(int i = 0; i < list2.length; i++){
            System.out.println(list2[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Не относящиеся непосредственно к вопросу обсуждения о допустимости лёгких вопросов, о том морально ли отвечать на такое были удалены мной. Несогласным или тем, кто не в курсе, я рекомендую ознакомиться с [правилами сайта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help) и темами на мете (например,  [тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4578/213987), если останутся непонятными вопросы -- задавайте их пожалуйста на [мета-сайте](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com). Спасибо всем, что удержались от перехода на личности.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы получить длину строки, нужно воспользоваться методом [`String#length`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length()):

```java
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String[] list = new String[10];
        int[] list2 = new int[10];

        for(int i = 0; i<list.length; i++){
            list[i] = reader.readLine();
            list2[i] = list[i].length(); // <---
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < list2.length; i++){
            System.out.println(list2[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать так:

```
final int[] lengths = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))
            .lines()
            .limit(10)
            .map(String::length)
            .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
            .toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(lengths));
```